# What's failing in my Perl script? MySQL/getopt

Tags: mysql, perl

I wrote a script where I'm passing (optional, I hope!) command line arguments and sending them to a MySQL query. If any are omitted I want the query to basically ignore that argument. If I pass all 3, my query is working. If I pass the second (an integer) and the third (a letter) the script also works. But if I omit either the int or the letter I get no results.

I tried to fix this by using ISNULL and Coalesce in my MySQL query as I'm not sure if the declared variable is null or empty if I don't explictly pass them in my commandline argument.

Currently it works if I pass "Perl Script.pl -s Hockey -i 10 -l h, or
"Perl Script.pl -i 20 -l z", but fails under any other iteration of the 3 arguments.

What I want to know is
 1. Did I make the arguments optional as I intended? Should I be using getopts instead of getopt?
 2. What do I need to change in my MySQL query to get it to work as I intended? Why aren't ISNULL or Coalesce working?
 3. Is anything else incorrect with the way I'm passing or passing the data?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Getopt::Std;
use strict;

getopt('s:il');
our ($opt_s);
our ($opt_i);
our ($opt_l);
my $sport_search;
if ($opt_s) ($sport_search=$opt_s);
my $integer_search;
if ($opt_i=~m/\d+/) {$integer_search=$opt_i};
my $letter_search;
if ($opt_l =~m/^[a-zA-Z]$/) {$letter_search=$opt_l};
my $g_hash = function1($sport_search,$integer_search,$letter_search);
my $string = "Just a string!";
if (&function2($g_hash,$string) != 0) {
    print "No values found for '$sport_search'","\n";
};

sub function1 {

my ($lsport_search,$linteger_search,$lletter_search) = @_;
our $dbh = DBI->connect{"dbi:mysql:dbname=database", "root", "password")
or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sql = "SELECT * from Players_Sport where Sport like '$lsport_search' AND length(Player)<=ISNULL('$linteger_search',20) AND Player between 'a' and ISNULL('lletter_search",'z')";
my $hash_ref = $dbh->selectall_hashref($sql, 'Player')
or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->disconnect
    or warn "Disconnection failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
return $hash_ref;
}

sub function2 {
my ($l_hash,$variable_two) = @_;
my $hashvalue=();
if(keys $l_hash == 0) {
    $hashvalue = -1;
}
    else {$hashvalue = 0;
print "$_\n" for (keys %$l_hash);
};
return $hashvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your query:

```
my $sql = "SELECT * from Players_Sport where Sport like '$lsport_search' 
  AND length(Player)<=ISNULL('$linteger_search',20) 
  AND Player between 'a' and ISNULL('lletter_search",'z')";
```

Even if $linteger_search and $lletter_search are undefined in Perl, they will never be NULL in SQL because you have put quotes around them.  In MySQL, `''` is not the same as `NULL`.

You also have some typos:  `'lletter_search"` should be `'$lletter_search'`  Note you must end the quoted string with the same type of quotes that you started it with, but you started with single-quote and ended it with double-quote (actually, I'm surprised it didn't throw an SQL error).

You also forgot the `$` variable prefix before lletter_search.

It's more common to build the SQL string dynamically, including search terms only when your search criteria are non-null.

```
my $sql = "SELECT * from Players_Sport where true ";
if ($lsport_search) {
  $sql .= " AND Sport like '$lsport_search' ";
}
if ($linteger_search) { 
  $sql .= " AND length(Player) <= $linteger_search";
}
if ($lletter_search) {
  $sql .= " AND Player between 'a' and '$lletter_search'";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and interesting. I will make those changes and check it. Is doing it non-dynamically the way I did causing the failure?

Comment: Better to use bound parameters for correctness and safety, no?  (e.g., `... -s "Bill O'Karwin"`)  Something like:  `if ($x) { $sql .= " AND col LIKE ?"; push @params, $x; } ... $dbh->selectall_hashref($sql, 'Player', {}, @params)`

Comment: @picrow, yes, I agree parameters are better, but one thing at a time.  :-)

Comment: The missing $ and incorrect " was a result of me typing changes I made manually and making typos. I'm running the script on a VM, so for speed I just typed the changes instead of installing everything necessary for copying and pasting.

Comment: Well, okay, but regardless your use of `ISNULL('','z')` isn't going to do what you expect.

Comment: I made the changes you posted but it's throwing a syntax error at line 29 near ) {. "if $lsport_search) {"

I verified everything was changed exactly as posted.

Comment: It looks like I forgot a semicolon on my first line of code above.  I'll fix it.